great memory leak on lldb in C++ code on mac
I ran a small C++ program:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Solution
{
public:
    string minWindow(string s, string t)
    {
        vector<pair<int, int> > V;
        map<char, int> tMap;
        map<char, int> sMap;
        map<char, int> Map;
        int left = 0, right = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
        {
            tMap[t[i]]++;
        }

        cout << "tMap is " << endl;
        for (pair<char, int> temp : tMap)
        {
            cout << temp.first << "   " << temp.second << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;


        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            sMap[s[i]]++;

            cout << "now the sMap is " << endl;
            for (pair<char, int> temp : sMap)
            {
                cout << temp.first << "   " << temp.second << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;

            bool include = true;
            for (pair<char, int> temp : tMap)
            {

                if (sMap[temp.first] < temp.second)
                {

                    include = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (include)
            {
                cout << "find the answer" << endl;

                right = i;
                for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    Map[s[j]]++;
                    bool find = true;
                    for (pair<char, int> temp : tMap)
                    {

                        if (Map[temp.first] < temp.second)
                        {

                            find = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (find)
                    {
                        left = j;
                        V.push_back(pair<int, int>(left, right));
                        Map.clear();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(V.size()==0){
            return "";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        for(pair<int,int> temp : V){
            cout<<temp.first<<"   "<<temp.second<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        int answerLeft=V[0].first,answerRight=V[0].second,min=V[0].second-V[0].first;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        {
            if(min>V[i].second-V[i].first){
                answerLeft=V[i].first;
                answerRight=V[i].second;
                min=V[i].second-V[i].first;
            }
        }


        return s.substr(answerLeft,answerRight-answerLeft+1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution *S=new Solution();
    string s = "ADOBECODEBANC", t = "ABC";
    cout << S->minWindow(s, t);

}

...and debugged it. Then I found that if I set a breakpoint in a certain line ,the vscode will be stuck, and if I skip the line to set a breakpoint then it will run normally. But suddenly, I found that my MacBookPro M4 16G 's Memory was under a great pressure, only to found a lldb-mi took up 30G memory.
and the stange line is line11 : vector<pair<int ,int> > V;
and the picture is below:



Solution* S = new Solution(); -- The only memory leak I see is this one.  There is no corresponding call to delete S;.  But why do this when you could have simply done: Solution S;?

Having an unexpectedly large memory usage doesn't mean there is a memory leak.

To what @drescherjm stated, run your main function in a loop 100 times.  If you do not see the memory usage increase, then it is not a memory leak.  It is simply the heap manager doing its job.

Looks like just testing code has a trivial memory leak: https://godbolt.org/z/YGnaev74T anyway you algorithm looks over complicated.

Looks like you come from a language with reference semantics. Ans you have what is called a "useless use of new", in C++ you can just use Solution s; (as long as you don't need dynamic polymorphism). In fact in most cases in modern C++, the use of new/delete is a code smell. Either use move semantics, or std::make_unique or std::make_shared.. And regrettably these are things you will not learn by doing competitive coding (lots and lots of bad coding practices in competitive coding)

Unrelated: C++11 abolished the need to put spaces inbetween the > of your std::vector<std::pair<...>>

If I compile the program and run it  it will be ok, and if i set the breakpoint in another line it will be ok too ,but if i set breakpoint in the main and step by step debug it it will be stuck , how strange it is

IIUC, the memory of the program being debugged isn't relevant here.  In the memory trace, lldb-mi and not the debugee is that one that's taking up 34GB.  Your debug session probably isn't fully stuck, just that lldb-mi is causing so much swapping that you aren't making reasonable progress...

lldb-mi is pretty old and has been without a maintainer for quite some time now.  For most jobs (except interfacing to Eclipse) the lldb community is supporting the lldb-dap interface.  You might try switching to lldb-dap and see if you have better luck.  The VS Marketplace page on it has some useful info: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.lldb-dap
